# Clear float inside already floated div

Tags: html, css

Two DIV containers exist. Left and Right. Those are floated.

Inside "Right" I have different blogposts (also using float).
I try to use `clear: both` after each blogpost by inserting an ::after element.

Now a strange thing occurs: the first ::after element begins where the LEFT element ends (NOT the parent but the counterpart to the parent element). This results in a big gap and I have no idea how to get rid of this gap.
Meaning when you change the size of "left" in the CSS, the gap also changes.

Any advice is highly appreciated!

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  min-height: 100px;
  display: block;
}

#left {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 800px;
  float: left;
}

#right {
  margin-left: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}

.image {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
}

.text {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.text::after {
  content: "Clear Both here";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">
    Links
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div class="blogentry">
      <div class="image">
        Bild
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore
        eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
        euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blogentry">
      <div class="image">
        Bild
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore
        eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
        euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blogentry">
      <div class="image">
        Bild
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore
        eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
        euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blogentry">
      <div class="image">
        Bild
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the gap? What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I think you should leave the float left and right alone and learn grid or flexbox for this. You end up with a better solution.

Comment: @Siyah, the space between the first blog-entry text and the first yellow "Clear Both here". The first yellow bar is supposed to begin right below the first text but it begins next to the end of the white left DIV.

Comment: The `#right` element is not float, but it's block.

Comment: @Alexander - that's it! My god, I wasted so much time on that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, using `clear: right` instead of `clear: both`, on `.text::after`, negates that space as well.